# Can't use python PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to recognize a text inside a PNG image.
I want to use python PIL but I can't.
I did everything as google told me but it never works.
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 / 13.04 for this.
I've installed all libraries.. when I install PIL, it says

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
--- LITTLECMS support available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but if I run selftest.py then I get following

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- PIL CORE support ok
*** TKINTER support not installed
*** JPEG support not installed
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not installed
*** FREETYPE2 support not installed
*** LITTLECMS support not installed
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Running selftest:

---

Failure in example:
try:
 _info(Image.open(os.path.join(ROOT, "Images/lena.jpg")))
except IOError, v:
 print v
from line #24 of selftest.testimage
Expected: ('JPEG', 'RGB', (128, 128))
Got: decoder jpeg not available
1 items had failures:
   1 of  57 in selftest.testimage
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
*** 1 tests of 57 failed.

some help would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

PIL appears to be deprecated, try [pillow](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) instead

Answer (score 0):

There is a new fork of PIL called Pillow which seems to work more consistently than PIL for a lot of people. It's easy to install also. Look [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)(for info/docs) and [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow)(to install). Though I think `pip install Pillow` should work